# CSS positioning and alignment of rotated text

Tags: html, css

Cant find out how to left-align the rotated text. I have a sample Image and also a JSFiddle Example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/Romux/gknmcjo3/16/

It should finally look like this: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2icC8.jpg

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
}

.vrtcl {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  font-family: Barlow Condensed;
  font-style: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1em;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 53px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 38px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-top: 5px;
  ;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

a {
  color: #2B414C !important;
  font-family: Ropa Sans;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 1px solid #2B414C;
  width: 90px;
  padding: 18px 10px 18px 10px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="vrtcl">
    <h1>Skischuhe</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>der perfekte schwung ins tal</h3>
    <h2>mit einem präzisen auf dich <br /> abgestimmten renn-tuning</h2>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">mehr</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by left-align the rotated text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the `flex` property to put your link at the `bottom` if you also use the `writing-mode` property **made** to rotate the text .

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  background:rgb(98, 152, 171);
  padding:1em;
}

.column {
  flex-direction: column;
  padding:0;
 
}

.column a:last-child {
  margin-top: auto;
}

.vrtcl {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
/* actually 
 writing-mode:sideways-lr; would be the one , but not avalaible everywhere so,let's transform */
  transform: scale(-1)
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  font-family: Barlow Condensed;
  font-style: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1em;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 53px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 38px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-top: 5px;
  ;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

a {
  color: #2B414C !important;
  font-family: Ropa Sans;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 1px solid #2B414C;
  width: 90px;
  padding: 18px 10px 18px 10px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="vrtcl">
    <h1>Skischuhe</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="column box">
    <h3>der perfekte schwung ins tal</h3>
    <h2>mit einem präzisen auf dich <br /> abgestimmten renn-tuning</h2>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">mehr</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode
>
> The `writing-mode` CSS property sets whether lines of text are laid out horizontally or vertically, as well as the direction in which blocks progress. When set for an entire document, it should be set on the root element (html element for HTML documents).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `writing-mode: vertical-lr;` and rotate it by 180 degrees, and then set the  margins:

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
}

.vrtcl {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.vrtcl h1 {
  margin: 0.5em 0.1em 0.5em 1em;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  font-family: Barlow Condensed;
  font-style: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1em;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 53px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 38px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-top: 5px;
  ;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

a {
  color: #2B414C !important;
  font-family: Ropa Sans;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 1px solid #2B414C;
  width: 90px;
  padding: 18px 10px 18px 10px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="vrtcl">
    <h1>Skischuhe</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>der perfekte schwung ins tal</h3>
    <h2>mit einem präzisen auf dich <br /> abgestimmten renn-tuning</h2>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">mehr</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but then it's right-aligned. cant find a way to align text "SKISCHUHE" left

Comment: Reduce the right margin (the 2nd number in margin - 0.1 now)

Comment: thanks, but does not work on internet-explorer, any idea how to rotate there?

Answer (score 0):

Use the same `writing-mode` and `transform` properties as Ori Drori answer but you could change `.vrtcl` to a flex box and add another div before `h1` to push it to the right before rotation. The default rotation origin is `center` so that `h1` will be rotated to left side.

Css:

```
.vrtcl {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  text-orientation: sideways;
  width: 200px; --> example width
  display: flex;

}
```

Html:

```
<div class="vrtcl">
    <div style="flex-grow: 1"></div>
    <h1>Skischuhe</h1>
 </div>
```